# How do I use IMPORTXML to import just a limited range within a table, not the entire table?

Tags: xpath, google-sheets, google-sheets-query, google-sheets-formula

I'm using Google Sheets to scrape a website table using the `IMPORTXML` function. The initial XPath obviously only references a single cell in that table so I'm wondering how to alter the syntax to import only the first 100 rows of the second column.

I've tried using IMPORTHTML but the syntax seems to be even more limited.

```
=importxml(B4,"//*[@id='historical-data']/div/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[1:100]/td[2]")
```

The above code gives the following error:

> "Imported XML content cannot be parsed."

Comment: what's the url?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I switched IMPORTXML for IMPORTHTML to give quite an elegant solution:

```
=query(importhtml(B4,"table",1),"select Col2 limit 110 offset 1",0)
```

Shoutout to @player0 for getting me 90% there.

Comment: Do not user answers as comments.

Comment: It is the answer, but I have to wait two days to accept it as such.

Answer (score 2):

try this perhaps:

```
=QUERY(IMPORTXML(B4, "//*[@id='historical-data']/div/div[2]/table/tbody/tr/td[2]"), 
 "limit 100", 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

The `[1:100]` syntax does not work. Try `[position()<=100]` instead:

```
=importxml(B4,"//*[@id='historical-data']/div/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[position()<=100]/td[2]")
```